# Regular expressions and matching URLs with metacharacters

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble finding a regular expression that matches the following String.

```
Korben;http://feeds.feedburner.com/KorbensBlog-UpgradeYourMind?format=xml;1
```

One problem is escaping the question mark. Java's pattern matcher doesn't seem to accept `\?` as a valid escape sequence but it also fails to work with the tester at myregexp.com.

Here's what I have so far:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])+;http://([a-zA-Z0-9./-]+);[0-9]+
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: The original intent was to match all URLs that could be found after the first semi colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are putting the expression in a string, you need to escape the "\" as well. That is:

```
String expr = "([a-zA-Z0-9])+;http://([a-zA-Z0-9./\\-\\?]+);[0-9]+";
```

You also need to escape the "-" if it's not the last character in a character class ([...]) construct.

Comment: You can also put the - at the beginning of the character class.

Comment: Thanks codeka and everyone else that replied. After some testing, the following should match all URLs: ([a-zA-Z0-9])+;http://([a-zA-Z0-9./\\-\\?=~]+);[0-9]+

Comment: You want that first plus sign *inside* the parentheses: `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`, not `([a-zA-Z0-9])+`.  Also, as @DVK pointed out, you don't need to escape the question mark inside a character class; `[a-zA-Z0-9./?-]` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`[?]` matches "?"

Comment: I'd be tempted to use that in future instead of messing around with backslashes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to escape your backslash, if your expression is in a string. Something like `"\\?"`

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+);http://([a-zA-Z0-9./-]+)(\?[^;]+);([0-9]+)
```

Works for me on that RexExp Editor website.